# MATLAB - striped area under the xy curve (bending moment distribution)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

what I want to achieve is a classical bending moment distribution plot that may look something like that:

[image: Example of plot I want to create]

I tried to use area, xy, and bar plot and the last one is the closest to what I need - but it's still not what I can accept. I can use data in arbitrary form.

Comment: There are a number of file exchange entries that do just this. It is not builtin functionality. There is a great blog post that highlights them and shows examples [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/07/15/creating-hatched-patches/)

Comment: Thank you, surely I'll take a look at this method.

Comment: Or, you can hack it up, Draw the outlines first, then use `stem()` with no markers to draw the lines. One for the positive bits, one for the negative ones. But only if you're a special kind of lazy:D

Comment: This seems promising since the method proposed by @Suever results in bitmap plots only.

Comment: Oh, I haven't thought of that aspect. Then it really does have a fighting chance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35969233/5067311) is more general, and can be used for slanted stripes, here's a simpler solution using `stem` without markers and baseline:

```
x1 = -3;
x2 = 2;
upfun = @(x) -1/10*(x-x1).*(x-x2);
downfun = @(x) 1/5*(x-x1).*(x-x2);

x_dense = linspace(x1,x2,100);
x_sparse = linspace(x1,x2,20);

%// plot outline
plot(x_dense,upfun(x_dense),'b-',x_dense,downfun(x_dense),'b-');
hold on;
%// plot stripes
stem(x_sparse,upfun(x_sparse),'b','marker','none','showbaseline','off');
stem(x_sparse,downfun(x_sparse),'b','marker','none','showbaseline','off');
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, this worked nicely

Answer (score 4):

I would solve it manually generating the lines you want.

```
%some example plot
x1 = -3;
x2 = 2;
upfun = @(x) -1/10*(x-x1).*(x-x2);
downfun = @(x) 1/5*(x-x1).*(x-x2);
%set slope you want. Inf for vertical lines
slope=inf;

x_dense = linspace(x1,x2,100);
x_sparse = linspace(x1,x2,20);

%plotting it without the stripes. nan is used not to have unintended lines connecting first and second function
plot([x_dense ,nan,x_dense ],[upfun(x_dense),nan,downfun(x_dense)])

x_stripes=nan(size(x_sparse).*[3,1]);
y_stripes=nan(size(x_sparse).*[3,1]);

if slope==inf
    %vertical lines, no math needed to know the x-value.
    x_stripes(1,:)=x_sparse;
    x_stripes(2,:)=x_sparse;
else
    %intersect both functions with the sloped stripes to know where they
    %end
    for stripe=1:numel(x_sparse)
        x_ax=x_sparse(stripe);
        x_stripes(1,stripe)=fzero(@(x)(upfun(x)-slope*(x-x_ax)),x_ax);
        x_stripes(2,stripe)=fzero(@(x)(downfun(x)-slope*(x-x_ax)),x_ax);
    end
end
y_stripes(1,:)=upfun(x_stripes(1,:));
y_stripes(2,:)=downfun(x_stripes(2,:));
x_stripes=reshape(x_stripes,1,[]);
y_stripes=reshape(y_stripes,1,[]);
plot([x_dense ,nan,x_dense,nan,x_stripes],[upfun(x_dense),nan,downfun(x_dense),nan,y_stripes])
```

Example for slope=1

[image]

Example for slope=inf

[image]

Comment: Have you tried drawing slanted stripes? Your manual version would make that fairly easily possible (unlike `stem`).

Comment: That might be possible, but would require to calculate the intersection between the lines. Especially for something like `g)` a sladed stripe might be cut in half. My primary reason not to use `stem` was to keep all in one dataseries, allowing later steps like adding a legend to be simpler.

Comment: You're right, I haven't considered cases like `g)` for this. I wouldn't worry about legends, their `behaviour` can just be disabled. But I know this was just an example:) I guess it can also depend on what OP exactly needs.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Was simpler than I originally thought, at least when ignoring cases like in g)